# get all selected class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lists of elements which on click it will toggle a class to each of it.

The purpose is I want to post it with ajax.

My question is how do I select all the element with that specified class, and delimit each of them with comma ","

```
  <ul id="tobeselected">  
      <li class="selected">one</li>
      <li class="selected">two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li class="selected">five</li>
  <ul>

  <button>click to alert</button>  
  //end of form
```

Here is the sketch of jquery I mess up :

```
   $('button').click(function(){

       $('#tobeselect li.selected').each(function() {
            var dataselected = $(this).text();                           
       })
      alert(dataselected);   
      /*
       The expected result would be:
        one | two | five
      */          
   })
```

But no luck so far. Can anybody help, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you very much for everyone who have helped me solve this newbie function. I really appreciate it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   /*
>    The expected result would be:
>     one | two | five
>   */
> ```

Try creating an array `dataselected` , utilizing `.text(function(index, text))` to `.push` `text` of each `li.selected` element to `dataselected` array ; call `alert` with parameter `dataselected` array chained to method `Array.prototype.join` having parameter `" | "`

```js
$("button").click(function() {

  var dataselected = [];

  $("#tobeselected li.selected").text(function(index, text) {
    dataselected.push(text)
  });
  
  alert(dataselected.join(" | "));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id="tobeselected">
  <li class="selected">one</li>
  <li class="selected">two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li class="selected">five</li>
  <ul>

  <button>click to alert</button>
```

Comment: This clearly works with the example. I can't help to accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` to create an array of the text values from the elements, then `join()` to create the comma-delimited string. Try this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var text = $('#tobeselect li.selected').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();                           
   }).get().join(',');
   console.log(text); 
})
```

In the console you would see:

```
"one,two,five"
```

You can amend the delimiter as required in the value you provide to the `join()` function. Also note that the `id` of the `ul` element doesn't match what you have in your jQuery selector.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. Well,  in the console log it prints the text in the selected elements. But the weird is when I alert it. It only alert one of selected element and then alert the name of the class. How do I solve this? I think it will be a problem when I post it with ajax?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Your question mentions nothing about AJAX?

Comment: No, it is probably not about ajax. but it is about the way it returns the data and how it would be next.

Answer (score 2):

This should work to output `one,two,five`

```
var separator = '';
var dataselected;
$('#tobeselected li.selected').each(function() {
    dataselected += separator + $(this).text();
    separator = ',';
});
```

Comment: Thanks claudio, for the answer.  what is the aim of `var dataselected` there.. It gives me error notification in my editor?

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedValues = "";

$('.selected').each(function(){
    selectedValues += $(this).text() + " | ";
});

alert(selectedValues);
```

Comment: This will output an undesired `|` at the end (`one | two | five |`)

Comment: You are correct, and a more specific selector as you have would be better as well. `$('#tobeselected li.selected')`

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo, it is `$('#tobeselected li.selected')` instead of `$('#tobeselect li.selected')`

Answer (score 0):

You have used,`$('#tobeselect li.selected')` while you have no element with ID of `tobeselect`.It should be `tobeseleced`.